# What can White Walkers raise from the dead?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Seeing as how in *Game of Thrones* S06E05 ("Door")

> Summer (Bran's Direwolf) dies defending Bran from the White Walkers

Is there any limitations on what White Walkers can resurrect? Is there any chance of a comeback for that character?

Comment: Good grief, that's terrifying!  White Walking Fire Wolves would be pretty awful!

Comment: But then, I wonder if they could be controlled by a Worg as undead animals...  or if a worg could skin crawl into a white walker.

Comment: He could become a wight (not a white walker; they are different). But considering cgi budget, he could be shown for a few seconds or not shown at all.

Comment: @JesseWilliams That is indirectly what I am asking. I wonder where they could go with it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Summer was ripped apart.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Episode S02E10 showed us that the White Walkers can mount undead horses. But in the context of the show, it seems to be the only non-human species to be raised from the dead.

In the books, we furthermore get some tales

> "Some stories speak of them riding the corpses of dead animals. Bears, direwolves, mammoths, horses, it makes no matter, so long as the beast is dead. The one that killed Small Paul was riding a dead horse, so that part’s plainly true. Some accounts speak of giant ice spiders too."
>
> <sub>*A Dance with Dragons - chapter 7 (Jon II)*</sub>

an undead bear

> A snow bear crashed through the brush, huge and skeletal, half its head sloughed away to reveal the skull beneath. Summer and his pack fell upon it and tore it into pieces. Afterward they gorged, though the meat was rotted and half-frozen, and moved even as they ate it.
>
> <sub>*A Dance with Dragons - chapter 34 (Bran II)*</sub>

and a message from Hardhome

> "Dead things in the woods. [...]. Dead things in the water."
>
> <sub>*A Dance with Dragons - chapter 58 (Jon XII)*</sub>

Comment: So going by the books, there is a change it could get raised from the dead? So many possibilities if it happens! As for the bear, damn, Summer's a bad ass for eating rotten meat.

Comment: @akadian If Sam's findings are to be trusted, it would not even be the first time for a direwolf to be used by the WW. But as L16H7 stated, [CGI is expensive, you know](https://i.imgur.com/gyFc8.jpg).